# How do I get indentation after automatic line break?

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, multicol

Some lines are too long to fit in its column and gets split into two.

But to make it clear that it still one line, like in a song, I'd to have an indentation after the automatic line break.

```
\usepackage{parselines}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{parse lines}[\noindent]{#1\\}
            this line isn't too long
            but this one is most definitely way too long and should be indendet after the auto line break
        \end{parse lines}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is generally called a "hanging" indentation, which should help you search for how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure why you are using the parselines environment, but if you want hanging indentation you need to set everyline as a paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parselines}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{parse lines}[\parindent 0pt]{\hangindent1cm\hangafter1 #1\par}
            this line isn't too long
            this line isn't too long
            this line isn't too long
            this line isn't too long
            but this one is most definitely way too long and should be indendet after the auto line break
        \end{parse lines}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]